# Persisting state of whole application with Svelte store

Tags: svelte

Assume my App consists of nothing but some initial properties and a each-list of MyItem items

```
{#each items as item}
    <MyItem
        bind:initprops
    />
{/each}
```

with
MyItem.svelte

```
<script>
   export let initprops
   let state1, state2
   function changestate() {
      // do some changes to the state variables
   }
</script>
```

What is the simplest way to persist the state of the  whole application (including the internal state of each MyItem) with a Svelte local store?

I tried using a single store for an array of "state-objects" which I then bind to each `MyItem` properties/state (I had to export the state in that case, which already felt wrong).
But whichever way of combining `$`, `$:` and `bind` I tried I could only get the state to be updated on page reload *OR* saved to the store on change, but never both.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would not recommend storing the entire state in a monolithic way.

- Small changes to the store will cause checks and updates everywhere, even though it should not be necessary
- Depending on how large the state gets, storing it could cause performance issues
- Updating and migrating the state becomes more complex and Svelte stores are probably not intended to be used that way. As you noted, exporting internal state so it can be bound to the store is not a great idea.

Ideally, the items should have some identifier and each item creates its own store that syncs e.g. with `localStorage`, where the key contains the identifier to separate it from the other entries. If there is no sensible identifier, the item index could be used as a fallback (though this requires intervention if items are re-ordered).